# SQL - Joining two tables and counting items

Tags: sql

Alright, I'm trying to see how many products are provided by each supplier (Products and Suppliers being separate tables). I want the results to be displayed with the company name and the number of products that company has available. I'm not sure exactly how to set this up.

So far I have:

```
SELECT CompanyName, Count(ProductName) FROM Suppliers 
left join Products on Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID;
```

I'm not sure how to make the ProductName count specific to each company. I'd be eternally grateful for any help you might be able to provide me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

All you are missing is a GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT CompanyName, Count(ProductName)
  FROM Suppliers LEFT JOIN Products
    ON Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID
 GROUP BY CompanyName;
```

The use of LEFT {OUTER} JOIN means that if there are suppliers that do not provide any products, then the join will return a set of NULL values for the columns corresponding to the Products table.  The COUNT(ProductName) then counts just the number of non-null values, thus producing the answer 0 for companies that provide no products.  Very often, you'd use a regular INNER JOIN and then you'd not see the companies that provide no products.

Comment: Wow, I'm ashamed of myself. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I know this is an old question, but how do you use a `WHERE` clause with this, if you want to only show records where the count of ProductName is less than 10, for example?

Comment: Interpreted literally, you'd have to write the original query as a sub-query: `SELECT CompanyName, ProductCount FROM (SELECT CompanyName, COUNT(ProductName) AS ProductCount
  FROM Suppliers LEFT JOIN Products
    ON Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID
 GROUP BY CompanyName) AS A WHERE ProductCount < 10`.  However, the HAVING clause would be appropriate, after the GROUP BY clause, in the basic query: `HAVING COUNT(ProductName) < 10`.