# How to make null/none count 0 instead?

Tags: python, group-by, count, sqlalchemy

I have some sqlalchemy that counts rows with the value "3" and then prints out the count. It works fine if the count is 1, 2, 3, etc, but when there are no items, it prints nothing. I wanted it to print 0. So I added an if/else statement that didn't work (it prints nothing, no errors).

How would I do this? Here's my current code — not really sure if I should be doing this part in sqlalchemy or python.

```
q = (db.session.query(Article.snippet, sa.func.count(ArticleVote.id))
     .join(ArticleVote, Article.id == ArticleVote.article_id)
     .filter(Article.snippet == a_obj.snippet)
     .filter(ArticleVote.vote_choice_id == 3)
     .group_by(Article.snippet))
for snippet, count in q:
    if count is None:
        threevotes = 0
    else:
        threevotes = count
    print(snippet, count)
    print("threevotes", threevotes)
```

Update: I made it an outer join. That didn't help.

```
     .join(ArticleVote, Article.id == ArticleVote.article_id, isouter=True)
```

Update: I found a workaround. I don't think it's the proper way to do things, and I'm concerned it might be problematic somehow in the future, so if anyone has a better idea (or can tell me whether or not this could be problematic) that'd be great.

```
if 'threevotes' in locals():
    print("threevotes in locals")
else:
    print("threevote not in locals")
    threevotes= 0
```

Comment: Have to join (often a left join) on a known set. Otherwise, how to know what is 'missing'? There are simply _no results_ returned in `q` for these missing cases.. won't find a count is None anywhere.

Comment: And this is secondary from any syntax / indentation error(s): read the _exact_ error message, which will contain the line and other hints. If asking about syntax errors explicitly, make sure to include these additional details - _full_ error message and how it relates to the lines of code in the question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075018/sql-joining-two-tables-and-counting-items/4075032#4075032 and related questions for how to structure the query. Adapt as necessary. This is the same for all 'standard' SQL implementations.

Comment: Thanks, the error message doesn't seem to be coming up anymore, so don't think that was the issue (removed from question above). I think I understand what you are saying — there isn't a "None" value in the table, so perhaps I didn't word the title correctly. Is there any way to make the variable = 0 if there is a count with no results?

Comment: "Is there any way to make the variable = 0"? Yes: [left] join with the set of possible results, as per the linked question. The [left] join should be after the count so the 'missing' rows will be added with a value of 0. There should be some translation of this to SQLAlchemy.

Comment: For scaling reasons, it may be beneficial to also limit the possible set of entries (the rows on the 'left' side of the [left] join) - ie. SO currently has ~20M questions (?); however, a query might only be interested in ones for the last week. This would limit the possible set to much less. 20M is still a small number for a RDBMS.. however, these 'negative queries' can become costly as data size increases.

Comment: I don't think SQLAlchemy has left join? The question seems to be in MySQL.

Comment: 1) SQLAlchemy _does_ have a left join, as found with a [simple search](https://www.google.com/search?q=SQLAlchemy+has+left+join) and shown in answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/39669377/2864740 2) SQLAlchemy hides the implementation. The RDBMS could be MySQL or SQL Server or SQLite or.. the _same_ underlying SQL query is used in these implementations. If the question is "How can I write this in _raw_ SQL?", it's a different question. The linked question above shows how to write such raw SQL.

Comment: I added isouter=True, but that didn't seem to change anything. Is there a simpler way to do this than to change the query? I'm concerned that'll mess up other things, as the query works well now for all other situations. Maybe some way to say "if the count is less than 1, make the count 0" or something? I'm not familiar with either MySQL or SQLAlchemy, so I'm hoping for a beginner-friendly answer.

Comment: Adding something random won't yield the result - it takes a query structure change. Reading [and understanding] the [previously linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4075032/2864740) (also see related questions from that question) is key to solving this request. It would probably be useful to try such queries in MySQL directly first, and then translate those to code / SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Also, perhaps https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/174694/123892

Comment: These answers all seem to focus on using outer join. I'm already doing that. I searched/tried stuff from SE for a long time before asking this — I suspect that there is some nuance here someone familiar with this stuff can see that I can't.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old question, but I was looking for the same answer
and here is my approach

**RAW SQL:**

```
select
cp.id,
case
    when w.quantity isnull then 0
    else w.quantity
end
from case_property cp
left outer join (
SELECT
    single_sma_workups.case_property_id AS case_property_id,
    count(single_sma_workups.case_property_id) AS quantity
FROM single_sma_workups
GROUP BY single_sma_workups.case_property_id
) w on w.case_property_id = cp.id;
```

**SQLAlchemy:**

```
workups_subquery = (
    db.session.query(
        SingleCMAWorkups.case_property_id,
        func.count(SingleCMAWorkups.case_property_id).label("quantity")
    )
    .group_by(SingleCMAWorkups.case_property_id)
    .subquery()
)

query = (
    db.session.query(
        CaseProperty.id,
        db.case(
            [
                (workups_subquery.c.quantity.is_(None), 0),
            ],
            else_=workups_subquery.c.quantity
        )
        # workups_subquery.c.quantity
    )
    .outerjoin(workups_subquery, CaseProperty.id == workups_subquery.c.case_property_id)
)
items = query.all()
```